# error compile openssl/demo/ssl/serv.cpp openssl

Tags: c++, openssl

When I try compile serv.cpp from openssl/demo/ssl :

```
g++ serv.cpp -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/ipsec -o -lssl -lcrypto -ltls
```

I get next error:

```
serv.cpp:58:53: error: ‘TLS_server_method’ was not declared in this scope
   meth = const_cast<SSL_METHOD *>(TLS_server_method());
```

Comment: I'm using latest version Openssl from git repository.

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

Answer (score 0):

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/TLSv1_server_method.html

TLSv1_server_method(), TLSv1_1_server_method(), TLSv1_2_server_method().